# Working with objects in array

Tags: java

I got a text file with hundred of lines. It is look something like this:
*unitName unitPackage unitPrice*. I got to sort it and sum up. For example we got these four lines:

```
foo1 01abc 30.00

foo2 02abc 31.50

foo1 04abc 35.00

foo1 01abc 30.00
```

After the work on i have to get it like this:

```
foo1 2 (01abc) 60.00

foo2 1 (02abc) 31.50

foo1 1 (04abc) 35.00
```

My idea was to make product class (*String unitName, String unitPackage, double unitPrice*) and put it to arraylist something like that:

```
List<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();

    while (inputFile.hasNextLine()) {
        Product product = new Product(inputFile.next(), inputFile.next(), inputFile.nextDouble());
        products.add(product);
    }
```

Until that moment all works fine, but I dont get idea, how to sort up things. It's overall good concept to do this like this way? Please about advice.

Comment: Sorting is certainly not the best approach to this. You are just grouping the values and the order seems to be unimportant. Using a `HashMap` to group the entries by `(unitName, unitPackage)` should result in a better performance.

Comment: Please format your question properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to get an array list sorted. In your particular case, where you put every item into a list, maybe the simplest form is use a Map implementation, i.e. HashMap, instead of an ArrayList.

After loop of insertions you can get the sorted list through values() method of the map.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to sort a List you can use the method `sort` in the class `Collections`

```
public static <T> void sort(List<T> list,
        Comparator<? super T> c)
```

To use it you need to create a `Comparator` that define how to sort your items.

```
List<Product> products = ...
...
Collections.sort(products, new Comparator<Product>() {
    compare(Product o1, Product o2) {  
         // Here define how to compare two products
    }
});
// Here products is sorted as you defined before
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make your products comparable by implementing `Comparable<T>` (see [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html)).
After doing so, you have to implement `compareTo(Product o)` which compares your products by the attributes you read. Please read the docs for more details.

Then you can sort your data structure e.g. by using `Arrays.sort(Object[] objs)` (transformation into array and into list again shouldn't be a problem).

But anyway, I prefer Davide Lorenzo MARINO's way by using a Comparator if you do not often need this logic. If you often want to compare products, use the way of implementing `Comparable<T>`.